# Testing Typescript with Mocha

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

I'm trying to test a NodeJS project written in Typescript with Mocha and I got the mocha.d.ts file from Definitely Typed

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/mocha/mocha.d.ts.

Here's the error I'm seeing in Webstorm:

```
C:/Users/Me/AppData/Roaming/npm/tsc.cmd --sourcemap Test.ts --module commonjs
C:/Users/Me/WebstormProjects/Core/test/External/mocha.d.ts(76,1): error TS2152: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
C:/Users/Me/WebstormProjects/Core/test/External/mocha.d.ts(78,1): error TS2152: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
```

This is the part of the mocha definition that's highlighted to show the error:

```
declare function setup(action: () => void): void;

declare function setup(action: (done: mocha.Done) => void): void;
```

Comment: In general, there is a lot of error highlighting in webstorm that is not present in the compiler. report a bug

Answer (score 0):

TS is picky about overloads.  See also [Constructor overload in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702548/constructor-overload-in-typescript)

Try deleting the first declare and adding a ? to the second to mark the param as optional (disclaimer - i haven't tested this)

```
declare function setup(action: (done?: mocha.Done) => void): void;
```

Answer (score 0):

That definition is valid. I suspect this is a WebStorm issue, or issue in your code elsewhere.

[See this compiles fine](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=declare%20function%20setup%28action%3a%20%28%29%20=%3E%20void%29%3a%20void;%0Adeclare%20function%20setup%28action%3a%20%28done%3a%20number%29%20=%3E%20void%29%3a%20void;) :

```
declare function setup(action: () => void): void;
declare function setup(action: (done: number) => void): void;
```