# How can I do constructor overloading in a implemented interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I tried to overload the constructor of a class which implements an interface but I'm getting the following error:

```ts
[0] app/foo.ts(12,5): error TS2394: Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation.
```

**Classes**

```ts
export interface Item {
    time: number;
}

export class Foo implements Item {
    public time: number;
    public name: string;

    constructor();
    constructor(
        time: number,
        name: string
    ) { 
        this.time = id || -1
        this.name = name || ""
      };
}
```

I found other similar questions ([Constructor overload in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702548/constructor-overload-in-typescript)) but I'm missing something because it doesn't work. The typscript versions is 1.8.9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation signature is not visible. You need to declare *all* the overloads callers should see, then write the implementation body.

```
export interface Item {
    time: number;
}

export class Foo implements Item {
    public time: number;
    public name: string;

    constructor();
    constructor(
        time: number,
        name: string
    );
    constructor(
        time?: number,
        name?: string
    ) { 
        this.time = id || -1
        this.name = name || ""
      };
}
```

You can also read the [TypeScript FAQ entry on this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-am-i-getting-supplied-parameters-do-not-match-any-signature-error)