# Error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'groupBy' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, typescript

I am facing an issue when i am trying to create a JSON structure like below:

[image]

so for this i am doing like below:

```
    class Aggregate{
    average: Number;
    count: String;
    max: Number;
    min: Number;
    total: Number;
    constructor(average,count,max,min,total) {
        this.average= average;
        this.count=count;
        this.max=max;
        this.min= min;
        this.total=total;
    }
}

var average = new Aggregate(43.833333333333336, 6, 90, 10, 263);
var aggregate = new Aggregate(0, undefined, 0, 0, 0);
var startDate=new Date("Tue Jul 05 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
var endDate=new Date("Tue Jul 05 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
interface date{
    aggregate: Aggregate;
    endDate: Date;
    groupBy: String;
    metricType: String;
    quarters: Array<DateMetric>;
    startDate: Date;
    type: String;
    quarter?: Number;
}
class DateMetric{
    aggregate: Aggregate;
    endDate: Date;
    groupBy: String;
    metricType: String;
    quarters: Array<DateMetric>;
    startDate: Date;
    type: String;
    quarter?: Number;

    constructor();
    constructor(obj: date);
    constructor(obj?: any) {
        this.aggregate= aggregate;
        this.endDate=endDate;
        this.groupBy=obj.groupBy;
        this.metricType= obj.metricType;
        this.quarters = obj.quarters;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.type = obj.type;
        this.quarter =obj.quarter;

    }    
}
var b = new DateMetric();
b.aggregate = aggregate;
b.quarter=4
b.startDate = startDate;


var a = new DateMetric({ aggregate: average, endDate: endDate, groupBy: "datetime", metricType: "distance_metric", quarters: [b], startDate: startDate, type: "person" })
```

but here i am getting an error saying:`Cannot read property 'groupBy' of undefined`

I have no idea why i am getting the error as `obj` in constructor should contain the object passed when creating an object `a`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you see in `console.log(obj)` inside constructor in DateMetric?

Comment: The error is caused by `var b = new DateMetric();`. It doesn't use 1st constructor, in stead uses 3rd.

Comment: @notgiorgi

but why so? It is not parameterised

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12702786/5341953

Comment: @notgiorgi

Thanks for the reference ,
but i here need to access non-parameterised constructor through b .How can i do it?

Comment: You can not. Your implementation of constructor (in this case `constructor(obj?: any)`) should take care of all the cases, including no parameters provided: `constructor();` and date as parameter: `constructor(obj: date);`. So you should do the checks to see if arguments were provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your constructor like this to get rid of the error.

```
constructor(obj: any | Date = {}) { }
```

this way if you create an instance without any data passed in the constructor, basically you are accessing.

```
{}.groupBy; // ({} aka 'obj' is now defined)
```

With your existing code you can also just go ahead and put an if, like so:

```
constructor(obj: any | Date) { 
    if(!!obj) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

But for your example above, the first solution is best in my opinion :)