# Pass array to variadic function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a method that should accept either an array of numbers or accept a variable number of number arguments (variadic). In most languages I've used, when you make a method/function variadic, it accepts both, but it seems that in TypeScript, you cannot. When I make this particular function variadic, all of the places where I supply a `number[]` fail compilation.

Signature for reference (in class `ObjectIdentifier`):

```
constructor(... nodes : number[]) {
```

This fails:

```
return new ObjectIdentifier(numbers);
```

where `numbers` is of type `number[]`.

Comment: Overload the constructor signatures: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12702786/6680611

Answer (score 20):

Use the following syntax:

```
const func = (...a: number[]) => console.info('a', a)

func(1, 2, 3)

func(...[1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach:

```
class ObjectIdentifier {
  public myNodes: number[];
  constructor(first?: number | number[], ...rest: number[]) {
    this.myNodes =
      first === undefined
        ? []
        : first instanceof Array
          ? [...first, ...rest]
          : [first, ...rest];
  }
}
const empty = new ObjectIdentifier();
const a = new ObjectIdentifier(1);
const b = new ObjectIdentifier([1]);
const c = new ObjectIdentifier(1, 2, 3);
const d = new ObjectIdentifier([1, 2, 3]);
const e = new ObjectIdentifier([1, 2, 3], 4, 5, 6);
```

The only quirk is seen in that last case where you can pass an array as the first parameter followed by a variable number of numbers.

Comment: This should only be used if you can't control that you are being called in both ways, otherwise just use the spread operator when passing an array