# angular 6 constructor overloading

Tags: angular, typescript, constructor, overloading

I am new to typescript/angulat. I already have a constructor fetching JsonP. I want to create a new constructor for HttpClientModule. This is my current code.

```
export class DataService {
    constructor(private _jsonp: Jsonp) {
        this.apikey = 'xxx';
    }
}
```

This is what I tried..

```
export class DataService {
    constructor(private _jsonp: Jsonp, private http: HttpClient) {
        this.apikey = 'xxx';
    }
}
```

The first json api stops working. I want something equivalent to this

```
export class DataService {
    constructor(private _jsonp: Jsonp) {
        this.apikey = 'xxx';
    }
    constructor(http: HttpClient) {}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constructor overload in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702548/constructor-overload-in-typescript)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Overloading is possible in TypeScript, please see this question:
[Constructor overload in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702548/constructor-overload-in-typescript)

Another common practice is to provide an optional parameter to functions that can contain options. Something like:

```
export class DataService {
  constructor(private _jsonp: Jsonp, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.apikey = 'xxx';
  }

  get(params?, options?) {
    if (this.options && this.options.service === 'jsonp') {
     // use the _jsonp service
    } else {
     // user the http service
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is outdated, as TypeScript definitely supports constructor overloads.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in Typescript it could look something like the following. Basically, you provide the method signatures and then the implementation (which has to handle all of the various signatures).

```
export class DataService {
    constructor(private _jsonp: Jsonp);
    constructor(http: HttpClient);

    // Implementation of the constructor
    constructor(api: Jsonp | HttpClient){
        // some sort of test to tell what type the parameter is
        if (/* api is Jsonp */) {
            // is Jsonp, not HttpClient
            this.apikey = 'xxx';
        }
    }
}
```