# Constructor Overloading in Typescript Not Working as Described

Tags: typescript, constructor-overloading

I'm really new to TS, and was working on a small game, but needed a `Vector` class. I needed the vector to be constructed from 2 types of sources, a `pos` vector and `size` vector, or  `x`, `y`, `w`, `h` values. I had looked at some answers here: [Constructor overload in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702548/constructor-overload-in-typescript), but the answers there did not work (or maybe I messed up):

```js
import { Vector } from "./vector";

export class Rectangle {

    private pos: Vector;
    private size: Vector;

    constructor(x: number, y: number, w: number, h: number);
    constructor(pos: Vector, size: Vector);

    constructor(pram1: number|Vector, pram2: number|Vector, pram3?: number, pram4?: number){
        if(pram1 instanceof Vector && pram2 instanceof Vector){
            this.pos = pram1;
            this.size = pram2;
        } else {
            // This part errors out
            this.pos = new Vector(pram1, pram2);
            this.size = new Vector(pram3, pram4);
        }

    }
}
```

I get 4 errors, all almost exactly the same to this:

```
src/js/game/rectangle.ts:16:35 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'number | Vector' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  Type 'Vector' is not assignable to type 'number'.

16             this.pos = new Vector(pram1, pram2);
```

Is this a TS bug, or did I mess something up?

Comment: Regardless of the error, I have a question for you: if the constructor is invoked with 4 numbers, which constructor should execute: the 1st or the 3rd?

Comment: What is `Vector`?  It helps if you include a [mcve] others can drop into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/DWKdow) and quickly demo the issue for themselves.  Otherwise we've got to do work just to get to the problem before we can even think of working on the solution.

Comment: The error arises because the `if` statement requires that `instanceof Vector` must hold for _both_ of the first two parameters. Therefore, in the `else` block it could still hold for one parameter but not the other.