# Dynamically change type based on variable

Tags: typescript, discord.js

So I really don't know if this is possible but I wanted to ask anyway. So I have a class named Row

```js
export class Row {
    buttons: MenuOption[] | ButtonOption[];
    rowType: RowTypes;
    constructor(buttons: MenuOption[] | ButtonOption[], rowType: RowTypes) {
        this.buttons = buttons;
        this.rowType = rowType;
    }

}
```

And it has a property called rowType which is basically an enum

```js
export enum RowTypes {
    SelectMenu = 0,
    ButtonMenu = 1
}
```

It also has a property called buttons and It can be either a MenuOption array, or a ButtonOption array. Now here's the problem. Can I tell typescript to change the type of the property buttons based on the rowType value? So for example if the rowType value is 1 then the buttons type is MenuOption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use constructor overloads so that you can ensure a 1:1 correspondence between `RowTypes` and the type of the `buttons` argument:

```
export class Row {
    buttons: MenuOption[] | ButtonOption[];
    rowType: RowTypes;
    
    constructor(buttons: MenuOption[], rowType: RowTypes.SelectMenu)
    constructor(buttons: ButtonOption[], rowType: RowTypes.ButtonMenu)
    constructor(buttons: MenuOption[] | ButtonOption[], rowType: RowTypes) {
        this.buttons = buttons;
        this.rowType = rowType;
    }
}
```

[See proof-of-concept on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwEoQO4BUCeYwAznAN4BQc1cAysADbADGMAsksnALxwAMAGio0AQshgwIiDih5wAjBQC%20FCgHo1cAFLJi8AIZwAJmlT44AS0QxgUAGb7mwOHehwwUCBDsBabz%20YpJzAYCisbe0dnGWQAeRCLKXJhahhCYAAuOAByVE5s5VUNbV0DY1NzcNsHJxc3Dy9ff0DEYNCqyNqxCSl4mETEZJo4NKIs7IAjcUlEApUKUEhYOGYGfWJSLGwhmimexGIsmL6BgG0AXTgAHzhumZOpC4BuFLhPPHSsrYIiYhfh14tPRQZCsaAACj2M0OcGOCUe5wEbxwP0ymBR6WIADp6ExWDEAJSAqTA0GSKCQ6YkrJ3XrwxAXJHvVFfDG-LG06ScInDIEwEFgilQ6mwzgPBmXG6c8WM5EfMbo%20UkAk7YapAAWFmxwoOch1f1ewxgmuxzPScjNRH%20NBU8z5cH18hpVMQMsuvFOZBGnxyOuycCU5xe9v1ACYjmL6Rc5J7vQrcvkA0GippYgBpLIABU8ADcLEYrABzOAAA2lUfOJZWEGQYCYRjg2AsxsVqOxnJiFEQwG2W0p%202I8iR30xHJdhJe6lTGbg2YgeYLiGLJbh-QRVcCtfrjeb6tbo9xLHYnC7PcV-ehoeHbJIOMYR4nKbgAFEMBhYhgs7n80XLK0IKgYD6P0ExMHGziSH%20gRQFAR77kQp69jgF4kle8G3h23IvN2SHYChBxDuh2KHviWFAA).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know that you could add multiple constructors.

Comment: @kalempster it's not multiple constructors, it's overloads - see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12702548/11407695) for details

Answer (score 0):

You can type constructor arguments to make code a bit cleaner, e.g.

```
type RowCtor = {
  buttons: MenuOption[];
  rowType: RowTypes.SelectMenu;
} | {
  buttons: ButtonOption[];
  rowType: RowTypes.ButtonMenu;
}

export class Row {
    buttons: MenuOption[] | ButtonOption[];
    rowType: RowTypes;
    constructor(args: RowCtor) {
        this.buttons = args.buttons;
        this.rowType = args.rowType
    }
}
```